# Check specific ID is exists in the table, show empty or null instead of showing No records found

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I have a table named Team_members, columns are team_id, staffid and stafftype and JOB table..I am fetching datas from job table.While fetching,

how to check if Team_id is not there in team member table (then return staff type empty field instead of showing No record found)?? or second senario if team_id is there in team_member table and check Leader(stafftype) is there belongs to that team_id.

Team table looks like

```
team_id team_name 
1        xyz
2        yux
3        iop
```

Team Member table looks like

```
team_id staff_id staff_type
1          13      Leader
1          14      Technician
2          11      Leader
```

//ASSUME 3 TEAMID IS NOT THERE IN TEAM MEMBERS TABLE

Staff table looks like

```
staff_id staffname
13         abc
14         tyy
15         fdg
```

Job table looks like

```
job_id jobdate     starttime   team_id
1      12-09-2018               1
2      12-09-2019               3
3      12-09-2018               1
```

I need to show Leader name in my html table

So I am searching records 3 (team_id) is not available in team member table. So am getting error. If 3 is available in team member table, I need to check Leader is available(staff type). If leader is not available means show Null in the html table column.

This below code is working if 3 teamid exit on the Team member table with stafftype "Leader". If teamid 3 is there in team member table with staff type Technician means it will show no records found..
Actually i need to show empty column if leader doesnt exists

```
    $this->db->join('team_members tm','t.team_id = tm.team_id');
    $this->db->join('staff s','tm.Staff_id = s.Staff_id');
    $this->db->where('tm.Staff_type', "Leader");
```

**PHP Modal function**

```
public function list_job_by_asignedteam($getselectedteam){ //value 3

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('job j');
        $this->db->join('team t', 'j.team_id = t.team_id');

        $this->db->join('team_members tm','t.team_id = tm.team_id');
        $this->db->join('staff s','tm.Staff_id = s.Staff_id');
        $this->db->where('tm.Staff_type', "Leader");


        $this->db->where("j.team_id",$getselectedteam);//value 3

        $this->db->order_by('Job_id', 'Desc');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return 'No Records Found';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Forget about the non-MySQL stuff for now. Instead provide a desired result corresponding with the data set provided.

Comment: @Strawberry am using mssql

Comment: Actually i want  to show empty column or null if Leader doesnt exists on the Team member  table ..Now the using the above code , all other select columns are  not coming becoz of Leader (stafftype) is not there

Comment: You have this: `$this->db->from('job j');`  What is the "job" table?

Comment: @DFriend I have updated the Job table plz check thius

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $this->db->join
('team_table','team_table.team_id=team_member_table.team_id')
->join('staff_table','team_member_table.staff_id=staff_table.staff_id');
      $this->db->where('team_member.staff_type','Leader')
->get('team_member_table')->result_array();
```

Comment: i just want to show only that field empty and other columns(from JOB table) need to showsup

Comment: Can i get any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
public function list_job_by_asignedteam($getselectedteam){ //value 3
    if ($this->isThereTeamLeader($getselectedteam)) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('team_members tm');
        $this->db->join('team t', 'tm.team_id = t.team_id');
        $this->db->join('staff s', 'tm.Staff_id = s.Staff_id');
        $this->db->where("tm.team_id", $getselectedteam);//value 3

        $this->db->order_by('Job_id', 'Desc');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        }
    }

    return 'No Records Found';
}

private function isThereTeamLeader($getselectedteam) {
    $this->db->select('team_id');
    $this->db->from('team_members');
    $this->db->where("Staff_Type", "Leader");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->num_rows() > 0;   
}
```

Comment: also Selecting other columns value from the JOB table..not only the staff type Leader..In your code if Leader is not avalable means other columns also will not show..I dont want to show like that

Comment: in this JOB table is missing..From job table only i am fetchingdetails of other columns

Comment: how to check if Team id is not there in team member table ?? or second senario if team_id is there in team_member table and check Leader is there belongs to that team_id

Comment: this is not working for me..Can u plz suggest any other answer

Comment: sometime team_id will be there in team_members table with other stafftype(technician) .So this wont work

Answer (score 0):

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('job j');
    $this->db->join('team t', 'j.team_id = t.team_id');

    $this->db->join('team_members tm','t.team_id = tm.team_id');
    $this->db->join('staff s','tm.Staff_id = s.Staff_id');
    $this->db->where('tm.Staff_type', "Leader");


    $this->db->where("j.team_id",$getselectedteam);//value 3
```

I think the job table have team_id 3 and team_member table have not team_id 3 so that why you have an issue. Check data table probably.

Comment: yes team_id 3 is there in Team table.And team_member table have not team_id..In this case i want to show in staff Name  column empty field